# mysql data type confusion

Tags: mysql, types, enums, int, sqldatatypes

So this is more of a generalized question about MySQLs data types.  I'd like to store a 5-digit US zip code (**zip_code**) properly in this example.

A county has 10 different cities and 5 different zip codes.

```
city   | zip code
-------+----------
city 0 | 33333
city 1 | 11111
city 2 | 22222
city 3 | 33333
city 4 | 44444
city 5 | 55555
city 6 | 33333
city 7 | 33333
city 8 | 44444
city 9 | 22222
```

I would typically structure a table like this as varchar(50), int(5) and not think twice about it.

(1) If we wanted to ensure that this table had only one of 5 different zip codes we should use the **enum** data type, right?

Now think of a similar scenario on a much larger scale. In a state, there are five-hundred cities with 418 different zip codes.

(2) Should I store 418 zip codes as an **enum** data type OR as an **int** and create another table to reference?

Comment: Addition to the accepted answer: INT(5) is also storing normal INTs. Explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14491272/857958

Answer (score 1):

Zipcodes should be integers... [MEDIUMINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) is what you're looking for. Few thousands different values is not good idea for `ENUM` - besides IIRC `ENUM` is limited to 64 different values.

You could create another table called `city` to store cities. The structure would be very simple: just standard ID + column for city name - `VARCHAR(50)` should be enought.
Of course you would have to add `city_id` to zipcodes table (with Foreign Key attached).

Answer (score 0):

if smallint unsigned (0 to 65535) is too small change to mediumint.

```
create table city(
 city_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
 name varchar(255) not null
)engine=innodb;

create table city_zip(
 city_id smallint unsigned not null,
 zip_code smallint unsigned not null,
 primary key (city_id, zip_code)
)engine=innodb;
```